# Sitemap Page to help new users to navigate

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

First let me point out that I'm not talking about `sitemap.xml` or anything like that. My search for `sitemap` only brought up these kind of questions.

---

In my opinion it would be very helpful, especially for new users of the *stackexchange* sites, to have a *sitemap page* which lists all the places a user can go to. A the moment some pages are only linked from certain other pages and then sometimes not very clearly. When I started to use tex.SX it took me a while to find the page which lists all the questions I marked at *"favorites"*. The link to it seems to be only on the user page below the *"About me"* text window where they can be easily overlooked for a while.

Such a sitemap page could simply list a *tree* of all relevant links on the site, maybe like shown below. The main links can be included again for the sake of completeness.

- Questions
- ...
- Meta
- User page

  - Stats
  - Activity
  - ...
  - Favorites
- Special Pages

  - Reputation listing (`/reputation`)
  - Election
  - ...

I shouldn't be work intensive to create the site, but IMHO it would be very valuable for new users and a good quick jump page for existing users, especially for pages they do not visit very often.

Comment: See also [this thread on meta.tex.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1001/2975) where we collect some possible links for this sitemap.